# Controller ng-model data different from ng-model data on the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, view

I am having an issue with using the data binded to my select boxes in the controller. When I display the selected data on the view using the ng-model variable it is binded to, everything works.  Now when I try to use those same values in the controller in a function instead of giving me the value selected it gives me the first value in the select.

I tried everything I know to fix it but couldn't figure it out... any help would be appreciated.  I figure I am missing some behavior.

The addProduct method is called using ng-click on a button.  The data shown is the result after clicking the button to populate that data.

Code for select boxes:

```
<div class="row select-options-container">
    <div class="col">
        <select class="product-options-select" ng-model="sizeOption" ng-options="o as o.size for o in selectOptions" data-ng-change="getIntensityOptions(sizeOption.id)">
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <select class="product-options-select" ng-model="intensityOption" ng-options="o for o in intensityOptions">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

View for what I displayed below:

```
<b>CONTROLLER VALUES</b>
<p><b>Size:</b> {{ newSize }}</p>
<p><b>Intensity:</b> {{ newIntensity }}</p>
<p><b>QTY:</b> {{ newQty }}</p>

<b>VIEW VALUES</b>
<p><b>Size:</b> {{ sizeOption.size }}</p>
<p><b>Intensity:</b> {{ intensityOption }}</p>
<p><b>QTY:</b> {{ productQty }}</p>
```

controller code for what I displayed below:

```
$scope.addProduct = function() {
    $scope.newIntensity = $scope.intensityOption;
    $scope.newSize = $scope.sizeOption.size;
    $scope.newQty = $scope.productQty;
}
```

[image: This is what I get on the view when I display the data]

[image: Select boxes]

PS - All this extra code was all used just to illustrate the problem.

Comment: whenever your model value changes, you need to call the addProduct method to re-initialise your 'view' values

Comment: Should of clarified that... those values are all called on ng-click from a button.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it does not look like you are updating the values on properly submit.

**Note:** If I am mis-understanding your goal, please comment and I will review again.

This *could* work if you were to set ng-model on the form element to be the same property as you are trying to set it to, but then you would not be truly submitting it, you would just be using the binding functionality that exists, example below:

```
<select class="product-options-select" ng-model="newIntensity" ng-options="o for o in intensityOptions">
</select>
```

My recommended solution however is this, to allow for a proper "submit" action to move the data from the page into the controller:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row select-options-container">
    <div class="col">
        <select class="product-options-select" ng-model="formData.sizeOption" ng-options="o as o.size for o in selectOptions" data-ng-change="getIntensityOptions(formData.sizeOption.id)">
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <select class="product-options-select" ng-model="formData.intensityOption" ng-options="o for o in intensityOptions">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- assuming you have a submit button of some sort -->
<button ng-click="addProduct(formData)">Add Product</button>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.addProduct = function(formData) {
    $scope.newIntensity = formData.intensityOption;
    $scope.newSize = formData.sizeOption.size;
    $scope.newQty = formData.productQty; // I don't know where this comes from, in the HTML the ng-model should be formData.productQty 
}
```

Comment: I will test it out in about an hour, I'm not by my laptop.  But I did try to submit it using addProduct(intensityOption, sizeOption) but it would still submit the first value